# Is it possible that the ampere high than the volt?

Tags: voltage, power, amperage, watts

Is it possible that the ampere high than the volt?
for exemple if i have 5v and 6A
and how its possible that there is 30 watt and 5 volt charger?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have your current being sourced at a higher number than your Voltage being sourced.

30 Watts / 5 Volts = 6 Amps